# Ansible installing boto3 on host using python2.7 Could not build wheels for botocore, since package 'wheel' is not installed

Tags: python, ansible

i try to install boto3 on Linux host using python 2.7
my ansible controller is using venv with python 3.7
using :

```
- name: install python2-pip
  yum:
    name: python2-pip
    state: present
- name: Upgrade pip
  pip: name=pip state=latest
  tags:
    - packages

- name: Ensure botocore and boto3 modules are installed
  pip:
    name: ["wheel", "boto3", "botocore"]
    extra_args: "--user"
```

but it gives me the error:

```
changed: [10.0.4.87] => changed=true
  cmd:
  - /bin/pip2
  - install
  - --user
  - wheel
  - boto3
  - botocore
  invocation:
    module_args:
      chdir: null
      editable: false
      executable: null
      extra_args: --user
      name:
      - wheel
      - boto3
      - botocore
      requirements: null
      state: present
      umask: null
      version: null
      virtualenv: null
      virtualenv_command: virtualenv
      virtualenv_python: null
      virtualenv_site_packages: false
  name:
  - wheel
  - boto3
  - botocore
  requirements: null
  state: present
  stderr: |-
    DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
    ERROR: boto3 1.13.1 has requirement botocore<1.17.0,>=1.16.1, but you'll have botocore 1.12.92 which is incompatible.
    ERROR: awscli 1.16.102 has requirement s3transfer<0.3.0,>=0.2.0, but you'll have s3transfer 0.3.3 which is incompatible.
      WARNING: The script wheel is installed in '/root/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
      Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: |-
    Collecting wheel
      Downloading wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
    Collecting boto3
      Downloading boto3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (128 kB)
    Requirement already satisfied: botocore in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.12.92)
    Collecting s3transfer<0.4.0,>=0.3.0
      Downloading s3transfer-0.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (69 kB)
    Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from boto3) (0.9.3)
    Requirement already satisfied: docutils>=0.10 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from botocore) (0.12)
    Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from botocore) (2.6.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25,>=1.20 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from botocore) (1.24.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: futures<4.0.0,>=2.2.0; python_version == "2.7" in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from s3transfer<0.4.0,>=0.3.0->boto3) (3.0.5)
    Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore) (1.9.0)
    Could not build wheels for botocore, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
    Could not build wheels for jmespath, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
    Could not build wheels for docutils, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
    Could not build wheels for python-dateutil, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
    Could not build wheels for urllib3, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
    Could not build wheels for futures, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
    Could not build wheels for six, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
    Installing collected packages: wheel, s3transfer, boto3
    Successfully installed boto3-1.13.1 s3transfer-0.3.3 wheel-0.34.2
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
  version: null
  virtualenv: null
```

**Solved:**
the order need to be this and remove the --user

```
- name: Ensure botocore and boto3 modules are installed
  pip:
    name: ["wheel","botocore","boto3"]
```

Comment: `my ansible controller is using venv with python 3.7 ` you mean that ansible was run from the terminal that had virtualenv activated?

Comment: i solved it see update